LookAt turning 90 degrees away form the point it should be pointing to, solved
I have a simple GameObject without scripts, an attack for boss to spawn. I assigned it in inspector and are instantiating it in bosses script, and then passing players position in transform.LookAt. However when its instantiated it looks 90 degrees away form where it should be looking.
This is the important part of the script:
var direction = (Player.Instance.transform.position)/* - transform.position).normalized*/;
GameObject spawnedThunderingStormAttack = Instantiate(thunderingStormAttack, transform.position, Quaternion.identity );
spawnedThunderingStormAttack.transform.LookAt(Player.Instance.transform.position); 

I tried changing direction; with or without normalized, and with subtracting transform.position
Example #1:


Example #2:


please show the local axes of the attack and the part of the attack you want to face toward the player

@Ruzihm the in local axes the red and blue axes are reversed

Sorry- by "show" I mean "include a screenshot or diagram in the question". And please indicate the part of the attack that is meant to face toward the player.

So after a while I found the problem; The forward axes changed, and rotation went to -90, but the object for some reason didnt rotate on global scale. I fixed it with replacing spawnedThunderingStormAttack.transform.LookAt(Player.Instance.transform.position); with this: spawnedThunderingStormAttack.transform.right = (Player.Instance.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
